# Angular 8 Directives from shared module is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

Hello guys! I am trying to make an angular 8 custom directive but it does not work for me, the browser console does not show me any errors but I do not visualize the changes or the console.logs that I have left inside the code, it is as if the directive was never called. Please someone help me! Thanks a lot. I have this, What I'm doing wrong?

```
// has-permission.directive.ts

import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[permission]'
})

export class HasPermissionDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input() permission: string;

  OnInit() {
    console.log('this.permission->', this.permission)
    console.log('text', this.el.nativeElement.textContent += 'It is working');
    console.log('--------------------------------------------------');
  }

}
```

```
// shared.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HasPermissionDirective } from '../directives/has-permission.directive';  //<-- My directive

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HasPermissionDirective],  //<-- Declaring
  imports: [ ],
  exports: [
    HasPermissionDirective,  //<-- exporting
    CommonModule,
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

```
//dashboards.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';

import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { ProgressbarModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/progressbar';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';

import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AlternativeComponent } from './alternative/alternative.component';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardsRoutes } from './dashboards.routing';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module'; //<-- Here

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardComponent, AlternativeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    ProgressbarModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forChild(DashboardsRoutes),
    SharedModule,  //<-- Here
  ],
  exports: [DashboardComponent, AlternativeComponent]
})
export class DashboardsModule {}
```

```
// dashboard.component.html
<h6 [permission]="permission" class="h2 text-white d-inline-block mb-0" >Default</h6>
```

Please help me!! T_T

Comment: I see a "strange thing". 1.- You export "CommonModule" in your sharedModule -I think you need remove it, 2.- Are you import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'; in your main module -not in the question-?

Comment: Yes you all right too, I will remove it from there. thanks so much!

Comment: your post is better than the angular documentation for sharing a directive inside a module, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class should implement OnInit life cycle hook (not mandatory, but a good practice) and the method should be `ngOnInit()`

```
export class HasPermissionDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('--------------------------------------------------');
  }

}
```

In the shared module as Eliseo mentioned you should only import the Common Module and not to export it.

Comment: That is correct. I have a bad implementation of OnInit life cycle... you are the best! **Thank you so much!!**

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it fixed your problem. Happy coding!

Comment: I doubt that this would help to overcome the issue mentioned above.

Comment: In my case I was not exporting the directive from the SharedModule. So exporting the directive from the shared fixed issue for me.

Comment: In my case, I was implementing the lifecycle but with the wrong name, I was using `OnInit` insted of `ngOnInit` @CharithaGoonewardena 